# Querying Couchbase view for single key with multiple values

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have document like below and i want to implement filter based on type in the range of timespan

```
{ fruit : Mango , timestamp : sometime  , ...},
{ fruit : Apple , timestamp : sometime , ...}
{ fruit : Grape , timestamp : sometime ,....}
```

My View's map function will emit like below .

`emit ([doc.fruit,doc.timestamp], callingSomeMethodGetFormattedValuelue());`

To query the records in a particular time period by  specific fruit type i'm using like
  `startKey=['Mango',sometime]` and `endKey=['Mango',sometime]`

My requirement is like , i want to filter by two type's of fruits  Mango and Apple , 
Can somebody help me to achieve that ? Can i Pass Array of  startKey and endKey !!.
The view i'm using also doing some complex logic's to format the data , can i achieve it without using N1QL

Comment: Why isn't N1QL a possibility?

Comment: The view i'm using doing some complex formatting on the output data that can't be done in N1QL